# Proof that a polynomial has a minimum in $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

I have to prove to following statement and I am having a really hard time here.

There it is:

Prove that the following polynomial has a minimum in $\Bbb R$

$$p(x)=x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$$

I tried to make the following proof, but I am stuck:

The polynomial can be shown like this:

$$x^4\left(1+\frac{a_3}{x}+\frac{a_2}{x^2}+\frac{a_1}{x^3}+\frac{a_0}{x^4}\right)$$

Let  $$g(x)=\left(1+\frac{a_3}{x}+\frac{a_2}{x^2}+\frac{a_1}{x^3}+\frac{a_0}{x^4}\right)$$

So we can now write the polynomial like

$$p(x)=x^4g(x)$$

Since $x,a \in \Bbb R$ we can say that $\lim _{x \to \infty}=\lim _{x \to -\infty}=1$ (from limit arithmetic).

We know that it is always the case that $x^4>0$, so the sign of $$p(x)=x^4g(x)$$ is determined by $g(x)$. For certain values, $g(x) <0 $ so we can say that there is some $a,b \in \Bbb R$ such that $g(a)<0$ and $g(b)>0$.

$p(x)$ is continouos everywhere, certainly in $[a,b]$, so from the Extreme Value Theorem, the function has a minimum in $[a,b]$.

There are two problems in my proof:

1. I can't find any value in which $g(x)$ is negative, only if there is some $a$ which is negative. What if $a$ is always positive?
2. If the first problem is solved, I managed to prove the statement for some $[a,b]$. Is it just enough? It seems to me that it isn't.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just write $f(x) = x^4 g(x)$ because $f(0)$ is defined and $g(0)$ isn't. Instead, you can simply prove
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = \infty$$
(because the $x^4$ term dominates all others in the limit)
With that settled, by the definition of these limits you can find some $R>0$ such that
$$f(x) > a_0 \qquad \forall x : |x|> R$$
(the $>a_0$ is arbitrary here, any constant works as long as $f$ attains it inside $[-R,R]$; also, $R$ need not be the optimal choice)
Now look at $f|_{[-R,R]}$. This is a continuous function on a closed and bounded set. You should have a theorem giving you that $f|_{[-R,R]}$ attains a minimum.
Since $0\in[-R,R]$, we know that this minimum is at most $f(0) = a_0$, so $f$ doesn't attain smaller values outside of $[-R,R]$ by construction of $R$.
This proves
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x) = \min_{x\in[-R,R]} f(x) \in \mathbb R$$
exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but how can you define a closed interval $[\Bbb R, \Bbb R]$?

Comment: @Alan $[-R,R]$ is the set $\{x\in\mathbb R \mid -R \le x \le R\} = \{x\in\mathbb R \mid |x| \le R\}$. I'm not defining anything like $[\mathbb R, \mathbb R]$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it.

Answer (score 2):

One could also note that the derivative of an even degree polynomial is an odd degree polynomial.  And an odd degree polynomial always has at least one zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any polynomial $f(x)$ of even degree with positive coefficient for the highest degree term. Check that as $x\to\pm \infty$ the polynomial values $f(x)\to +\infty$. That means there exist an $N>0$ such that
 for $a\in [-N, N], b\not\in [-N,N]$, we have $f(a)<f(b)$. Now the (global) minimum for $f(x)$ is attained in $[-N,N]$, a compact set.

Comment: Thanks. The last sentence is from the extreme value theorem? N is just a number, right? not the Natural Numbers set?

Answer (score 1):

The claim itself is true more generally for any polynomial of even degree with positive leading coefficient.

We do not need that $g(x)<0$ for some $x$ and in fact such $x$ may not exist. What we need is that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=1$ implies that there exists $M\in \mathbb R$ such that $|x|>M$ implies $|g(x)-1|<\frac12$ (so that $g(x)>\frac12$). Then for $|x|>M$ we conclude $f(x)>\frac12x^4>\frac12M^4$. We may assume wlog. that $\frac12M^4>a_0=f(0)$. Then the minimum the continuous function has on $[-M,M]$ is in fact a global minimum.

Comment: I know that this is an old comment but if it weren't $x^4$ one could do the same proof with just any positive leading coefficient of even degree. (As you stated in your answer). So we could conclude $f(x)\gt(1/2)x^{2k}\gt(1/2)M^{2k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and go on from there right?